# iOS RealmSwift Connection to realm file

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new to iOS and XCode. I made a new iOS project, installed realm successfully via CocoaPods. Everything works fine so far: saving object, reading objects and so on.

But when I restart XCode I lost the "connection" to the realm file, because the path changes every time I start the IDE/simulator.

Sorry, for my stupid question, but: How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: I guess there is nothing you can do about path changing, but you can log current path every time you run app like that `print("url = \(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!)")` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: How did you created realm file? Please show the code

Comment: @GienadijMackiewicz: Thank you so far!

Comment: @LalKrishna: Very simple, maybe too simple: `let realm = try! Realm()`

Comment: @Voland `Realm()` creates `default.realm` file in `Documents folder`. So I think, when you restarting xcode, the Documents folder may be deleted & creates a new one always on simulators

Comment: @LalKrishna Thank you. So is there a way to create a "permanent" path for the development process?